# How do you pass a character array

Tags: c, arrays, string, int, parameter-passing

I want to pass an array of characters i.e. a *String* in **c**

```
int main()
{
    const   char c[]="Joseph";

    TestWord(&c,&c);
    return 0; 
}

int TestWord(char tiles[], char  word[])
{
    return tiles; 
}
```

Comment: An array of characters is **not** a string. But a string is **stored** in an array of `char`. What is your question?

Comment: `const char *TestWord(const char tiles[], const char  word[])` , `TestWord(c, c);`

Comment: @Olaf how do I pass an array of 'char ' from 'TestWord' to 'main'?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *TestWord(char tiles[], char word[]);


int main()
{
     char c[]="Joseph";
     char r;


    r = *TestWord(c,c);

    return 0;
}

char *TestWord(char tiles[], char word[])
{
    return tiles;
}
```

You pass through the arrays without the `&` as arrays don't need those, as they are already somewhat like pointers, just like how you would `scanf` an array without the `&` symbol.

Don't forget that if you are returning `tiles` that you should save that in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

you could pass a string(character array) in C in many ways.
This code passes the string a to the function PRINT. Note that in this method the base address of the array is sent to the function.

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    void PRINT(char b[])
    {
        printf("%s",b);
    }
    int main()
    {
       char a[]="hello";
       PRINT(a);
       return 0;
    }
```